# Extract certain numbers of samples from left to right given index point of a signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals

There is a matrix `Idx = [1xM]` with M dimension of index numbers of a signal to be extracted. For each index number, from left to right certain numbers of samples should be extracted to form a new sub-signal of original signal. 
For example, 3 samples from left and 4 samples from right of an index number see below:

`[idx-3:idx+4]`

[New_Sig] becomes an one-row matrix instead of being the same dimension of index number from index matrix `[Idx]`

```
Fs = 500; %Frequency:500
StartIdx = 0.150 * Fs;
EndIdx = 0.500 * Fs;

[Idx] = [.....];
[New_Sig] = [Idx-StartIdx : Idx+EndIdx];
```

Here is an example for **two index points** from `Idx` matrix below:

```
[Idx] = [2 19 23 43 48 52 62 74 78 79 81]
old_sig = [-2 0 1 2 5 6 7 8 10 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 ...]

if # of sample from left = 3, # of sample from right = 4:

a_new_sub = [-2 0 1 **2** 5 6 7 8]
b_new_sub = [7 8 10 **19** 20 21 22 23]
.....
```

Comment: I see you are in a habit of writing posts, not questions. Questions in English are sentences which can receive an answer, and end with a question mark, ?. Since Stack Overflow is a **question** and answer site, it's mandatory to post a question. The reason for this is that it is otherwise difficult to figure out what exactly you want us to help you with. Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask], then [edit] your posts to contain a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my suggestion to solve this issue:

```matlab
StartIdx = 3;
EndIdx = 4;

Idx = [2 19 23];
old_sig = [-2 0 1 2 5 6 7 8 10 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29];

% Get number of "indices".
nIdx = numel(Idx);

% Find actual indices.
idx = ceil(find(repmat(old_sig, nIdx, 1) == repmat(Idx', 1, numel(old_sig))) / nIdx);

% Set up correct (index) ranges to access in old_sig.
idx = repmat(-StartIdx:EndIdx, nIdx, 1) + repmat(idx, 1, (StartIdx + EndIdx + 1));

% Determine output.
new_sig = old_sig(idx)
```

As output, we get:

```matlab
new_sig =
   -2    0    1    2    5    6    7    8
    7    8   10   19   20   21   22   23
   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
```

Caveat: At the moment, your `old_sig` contains unique values. Therefore, the `find` will find the correct (unique) index. If the values in your signal do repeat, one need to specify which value should be found.

Another caveat: Depending, on how large your signal `old_sig` is, and how many indices you have in `Idx`, this approach might get memory intensive.

Comment: The old signal is [1x10000] matrix and indices were [1x23]. Getting the following error.. `Matrix dimensions must agree '=='` `Error occurred: single_load (line 49)`
`idx = ceil (find (repmat (old_sig, nIdx, 1) == Idx ') / nIdx);`

Comment: @htetmyet Without seeing the code, you actually use, i.e. not that one in your original question, it's impossible to point out a possible mistake. What's `R_i`, what are its dimensions? Edit: Now, you edited `R_i` to `Idx`. Ensure, that you don't add any errors when "obscurifying" your original code before posting here.

Comment: `R_i` is `Idx` from my question, and it is [1x23] dimension, while `old_sig` has [1x10000] dimension.

Comment: @htetmyet Again, without seeing the rest of your code, it's impossible to further help you. `repmat(old_sig, nIdx, 1)` should provide a `[23x10000]` array, and `Idx'` should be a `[23x1]` vector, so that `==` normally should work, since it does elementwise comparison per row then. Is `nIdx == 23`?

Comment: `nIdx == 23`, is correct, and `Idx'` is also `[23x1]`. Everything provided here is the original code except the slight changes in variable names.

Comment: @htetmyet Ok, one last try: I edited my code, see the corresponding line. The right side of the comparison now explicitly has the same dimensions as the left side of the comparison.

Comment: It works like a charm now. Thank you for your quick response and solution. Appreciated.

Comment: @htetmyet Glad I could help. May I assume, you use an older MATLAB version, at least something before R2016b? In my initial solution, I used a technique called implicit expansion, which was introduced in R2016b. That allows arithmetics like adding matrices and vectors, which apparently failed for you. It took me a while to realize that. So, for future questions, I would suggest you to state which MATLAB you use. :)

Comment: You are corrcet, 'm working on R2015a. Thanks for your suggestion and noted for my further questions. :)

Comment: Have you tested your code with bigger matrices because it's returning `Empty matrix: 0x1` for `idx` when applying on real data.

Comment: @htetmyet A limited problem statement (that includes the lack of providing "real" data in the first place) leads to a limited solution. That's pretty common here on SO. I will now stop further "supporting" this issue. Ask a new question, providing your whole code (including the pretended erroneous part of my solution) together with your "real" data.