# What went wrong during arithmetics calculations in higher dimension matrix in Matlab R2015a

Tags: matlab, calculation

While performing arithmetics calculation below, with higher dimension matrix, it is not returning the result we expected. However, it's working with smaller matrix. The problem with higher dimension and its attributes are stated as follows:

`result = ceil(find(repmat(old_sig, nIdx, 1) == repmat(idx', 1, numel(old_sig))) / nIdx);`,

where `old_sig` has `1x10000` dimension, `idx` has `1x26` dimension, and `nIdx` is `numel(idx)` which is `26`.

The expected `result` should be: `26x1 dimension`, instead it's returning `0x1` empty dimension.

At least, `find(repmat(old_sig, nIdx, 1) == repmat(idx', 1, numel(old_sig)))` should return `26x1` dimension, instead of returning `0x1` dimension.

Comment: This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233611/extract-certain-numbers-of-samples-from-left-to-right-given-index-point-of-a-sig) to provide some more context. Setting `old_sig = -4999:5000` (`1x10000`) and `idx = randperm(10000, 26) - 5000` (`1x26` with proper "Index values" for `old_sig`), there's no problem with the code (which I provided in my answer to the afore-mentioned question). As I told you before more than once, please provide your whole actual code section as well as your actual `old_sig`!

Comment: The code that you have written is correct. The result you expect is actually wrong. There is no reason to expect a `26x1` vector from the `find` function unless you are sure that exactly 26 elements will match between the two matrices you create. What is happening is that no elements are identical between the two matrices leading to the empty vector result